# Watir Webdrive Failed to Connect To Running Browser

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I did not used Watir Webdriver with Chrome for a few weeks, today when I tried to use it I got error when i try to create a new Browser instance. This is the error that get:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\kai.knutson>irb
irb(main):001:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true

irb(main):002:0> e = Watir::Browser.new:chrome
Started ChromeDriver
port=9515
version=18.0.1022.0
log=C:\Users\kai.knutson\chromedriver.log
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(106): error: Value of: app_launched
  Actual: 1
Expected: AUTOMATION_SUCCESS
Which is: 0
Error while awaiting automation ping from browser process
[0821/155924:ERROR:proxy_launcher.cc(569)] Failed to ConnectToRunningBrowser
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(303): error: Value of: browser.get()
  Actual: false
Expected: true
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Unable to either launch or connect to
Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: C:
\Users\kai.knutson\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:59:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:92:in `create_session'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:29:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/s
elenium/webdriver.rb:65:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir
-webdriver/browser.rb:35:in `initialize'
        from (irb):2:in `new'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have selenium-webdriver 2.24.0, the latest version is 2.25.0. Update your gems (or at least selenium-webdriver) and let us know if the problem is still there. Also, get the latest chromedriver: http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Comment: So i updated selenium, but still get the same error. Here are all my versions of the relevant components.                                      Google Chrome:21.0.1180.83    ruby 1.9.3p194  watir-webdriver: 0.6.1 selenium: 2.25

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake the chrome driver i downloaded was not the newest one. Thank you Zeljko

Comment: Maybe you had the most recent chromedriver when you were downloading it, the new version vas released a day or two ago.